# Magma Cube Spawners in the Overworld?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

If I get a magma cube spawner and I place it in the overworld will it spawn magma cubes? This is on a server with the Nether disabled.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, a spawner block will spawn Nether mobs in any dimension, including the Overworld. (Assuming the block is correctly set up to spawn that mob, of course.) My kid regularly sets up mob battles in Creative by picking snow golem and Nether mob spawners out of NEI and placing dozens in a crater in the Overworld.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, however the only way to get magma cube spawners is through creative mode, or other forms of cheating. But there is no restrictions on spawning them in the over world if you did manage to obtain a spawner block